# Ubuntu server 14.04 quotations marks display wrong

Tags: command-line, openssh

When ever the character <kbd>'</kbd> is displayed in my terminal it displays as <kbd>â</kbd>.

I have never had this with the previous versions of Ubuntu.

For example:

```
rm: cannot remove â/etc/init.d/novncâ: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How are you accessing the server (via SSH?) - this is typical if the client interprets the remote character set as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

Comment: This occurs both over ssh and when i have a keyboard and screen attached.